# What doesn't IE11 like about my use of dispatchEvent?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have this line of JS:

```
f.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('submit', {detail: target.parentNode.id, cancelable: true}));
```

Which works in just about every browser/device I've tested, but doesn't in IE11, failing with this error:

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
```

How can I  fix this line so that it works in IE11 as well?  IE10 and older would be a bonus, but that accounts for less than 1% of my userbase so I can probably live without them.

Comment: Refer this [article](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrinokx.php)

Comment: Are you using any `fireEvent` in your code?